# Which audio playback technology do I need for this?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, audio

I have trouble choosing the right audio playback technology. There's a ton of technologies to use on the iPhone, it's so confusing.

What I need to do is this:

- start playing short sounds ranging between 0.1 and 2 seconds
- high quality playback, no crackle (I heard some of the iPhone audio playback technologies do a crackle sound on start or end, which is bad!)
- ability to start playback of a sound, while there's already another one playing right now (two, three or more sounds at the same time)

What would you suggest here, and why? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are basically four options for playing audio on the iPhone:

1. [Audio Toolbox](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/WhatsinCoreAudio/WhatsinCoreAudio.html). Easy, but only good for playing sound effects in applications ([sample code](http://gist.github.com/205857)).
2. [Audio Queue Services](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/index.html). Very powerful, can do anything. C API, pretty messy to work with. Callbacks, buckets, pain.
3. [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/index.html). About the easiest option. Can play compressed audio, with a simple wrapper you can easily play multiple instances of the same sample at once (non-compressed audio only, as there is only one HW audio decoder). Starting to play a sound with `AVAudioPlayer` seems to [lag about 20 ms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986983), could be a problem.
4. [OpenAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenAL). Decent compromise between complexity and features. Sounds do not lag, you can play multiple sounds just fine, but you have to do a lot of the work yourself. I’ve written a sound engine called [Finch](http://github.com/zoul/Finch) that can help you.

Don’t know much about cracking, never experienced it. I think there were some issues with playing seamless compressed loops with `AVAudioPlayer`, can be overcome by saving the loop without compression.

Comment: Finch looks great! Thanks for sharing your hard work with us. Which sound file format should I prefer with Finch? Which bitrate? Would be happe about some more advice on that. Thanks again! Really great. You saved my day.

Comment: Right now Finch should support mono and stereo little-endian WAV and CAF files sampled at 44.1 kHz. I’m not sure if all the combinations are tested, plain stereo WAVs at 44.1 kHz work for sure.

Comment: would you prefer CAF over WAV? What does little-endian mean?

Comment: I don’t know much about CAF, except that it’s a format that Apple uses. I use WAV. Little-endian is a way of storing the bytes inside the file, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianity.

Comment: Finch uses Audio Queue Services, right? Thanks a lot. Going to have a look at it.

Comment: Finch is a simple wrapper around OpenAL; the PCM decoder uses some functions from Audio Toolbox.