# Delay in playing sounds using AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer

```
-(IBAction)playSound{ AVAudioPlayer *myExampleSound;

NSString *myExamplePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myaudiofile" ofType:@"caf"];

myExampleSound =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:myExamplePath] error:NULL];

myExampleSound.delegate = self;

[myExampleSound play];

}
```

I want to play a beep sound when a button is clicked. I had used the above code. But it is taking some delay in playing the sound.

Anyone please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two sources of the delay. The first one is bigger and can be eliminated using the `prepareToPlay` method of `AVAudioPlayer`. This means you have to declare `myExampleSound` as a class variable and initialize it some time before you are going to need it (and of course call the `prepareToPlay` after initialization):

```
- (void) viewDidLoadOrSomethingLikeThat
{
    NSString *myExamplePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
        pathForResource:@"myaudiofile" ofType:@"caf"];
    myExampleSound =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
        [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myExamplePath] error:NULL];
    myExampleSound.delegate = self;
    [myExampleSound prepareToPlay];
}

- (IBAction) playSound {
    [myExampleSound play];
}
```

This should take the lag down to about 20 milliseconds, which is probably fine for your needs. If not, you’ll have to abandon `AVAudioPlayer` and switch to some other way of playing the sounds (like the [Finch sound engine](http://github.com/zoul/Finch)).

See also my own question about [lags in AVAudioPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986983).

Answer (score 1):

`AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` is an option. Tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/259/audio-101-for-iphone-developers-playing-audio-programmatically), sample code [here](http://gist.github.com/205857).

Comment: But you cannot control volume with this.

Comment: You can only play one sound at a time with this as far as I know.

Comment: In my experience, `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound()`'s delay is just a long or longer than `AVAudioPlayer#.play()`'s.