# Trying to fix AVAudioPlayer lag on its initial use

Tags: ios4, avaudioplayer, delay, lag

This issue has shown up in several other question here on SO:

[Slow start for AVAudioPlayer the first time a sound is played](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900461/slow-start-for-avaudioplayer-the-first-time-a-sound-is-played)

[Delay in playing sounds using AVAudioPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550480/delay-in-playing-sounds-using-avaudioplayer)

I've tried implementing the fixes suggested but none of them are solving my problem.  My application presents the user with a grid of objects to touch, when an object is touched a sound is played.  This works great except on the initial touch there is a delay of ~2 seconds.

To get around this I initialize my audio player with a dummy aiff file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    NSString *soundFile = [Card loadCardSoundPath:@"dummy"];

    AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                             [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile] error:nil];
    self.audioPlayer = player;
    [audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
//    [audioPlayer play];
    [player release];
...
[super viewDidLoad]; 
}
```

Then when an object is touched I call:

```
NSString *soundFile = [Card loadCardSoundPath:name];

if (soundFile != nil){

            AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                                     [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile] error:nil];
            self.audioPlayer = player;
            [self.audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
            [self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
            [self.audioPlayer play];
            [player release]; 
}
```

The behavior i'm observing is this: I observe the audio delay when I click the first object if I create a dummy audio player and call prepareToPlay but not play.  However if I call play on the dummy audio player then I don't get the delay on the initial object but the view load gets delayed by 2 seconds.

Is there a way to get around this?  Should I simply create an NSArray of AVAudioPlayers on load and tell them all to prepare to play, and then just call play when the object is clicked?

Comment: I ended up creating an NSArray containing AVAudioPlayer objects that have all had prepareToPlay called on them.  This works pretty well, although i'm hoping someone will propose a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes it can help to let `viewDidLoad` return by spooling off initialization like that using `peformSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`. For example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    // initialization ...
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    [self performSelector:@selector(primeAudioPlayer) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}

-(void)primeAudioPlayer {
    NSString *soundFile = [Card loadCardSoundPath:@"dummy"];

    AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                             [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile] error:nil];
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [player release];
}
```