# AVAudioPlayer Intermittent Start Delay

Tags: swift, delay, avaudioplayer

I did a basic implementation of an `AVAudioPlayer`:

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setMode(.default)
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
    
    guard let urlStringBoltDown = urlStringBoltDown else {
        return
    }
    
    player4 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: urlStringBoltDown))
    
    guard let player4 = player4 else {
        return
    }
    
    player4.prepareToPlay()
    
} catch {
    print("oops")
}
```

When playing the sound (about .5 seconds long), I have both delay and lag. With the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25503629/avaudioplayer-produces-lag-despite-preparetoplay-in-swift) I managed to get rid of the lag:

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    self.player4?.play()
}
```

Despite calling `player4.prepareToPlay()` (as suggested in multiple answers, for example: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550480/delay-in-playing-sounds-using-avaudioplayer)) right after the initialisation in `ViewDidLoad()` I still get a delay on the first run (about 2 seconds). This delay does disappear after playing the sound once, but not permanently. If I play the sound again on this particular player or any other in about 3 seconds, there is no delay. Otherwise, it reappears.

I tried:

- calling `prepareToPlay()` after every sound played (nothing)
- calling `prepareToPlay()` in `ViewDidAppear()` (nothing)
- playing and the stopping the player after every sound (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900461/slow-start-for-avaudioplayer-the-first-time-a-sound-is-played)). Again, this removed the delay for every `.play()` in the next 3 seconds or so, anything after having the same delay

It would be really helpful if I could check whether the player is actually ready to play or not after calling `prepareToPlay()`, but I only found methods of checking an `AVPlayer` status. If someone could point out how to do this I might solve the problem or at least add some valuable information to this question.

I just want a way to remove the delay permanently. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Started a bounty, thanks for asking this question.  This is happening to my app only when playing AVAudioPlayer files over a bluetooth speaker. It doesn't happen for me over the device speaker, or AirPods.

Comment: @JoshuaHart generally, bluetooth latency is a feature, and you better asking your question separately, detailing your app scenario, bluetooth version, audio codec, device manufacturer.

Comment: Have you tried to instantiate an AVAudioPlayer in a private queue? That seems to be a pretty resource consuming operation. Take a look at Mocha's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25503629/avaudioplayer-produces-lag-despite-preparetoplay-in-swift